# How to enable "distributable" programmatically with WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: spring, tomcat7, web.xml, spring-java-config, session-replication

Our webapp is configured using spring's WebApplicationInitializer like:

```java
@Order(1)
public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        // how to enable "distributable" here?
    }
}
```

This app will run on a tomcat cluster and must therefore be marked as "distributable" (as explained [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#Cluster_Basics)). This normally happens by adding the "distributable" element to the web.xml.
How do I mark my webapp as distributable with java based config?

Comment: You cannot. This part is missing (just as some session settings, error pages and welcome pages) from the java api. You will have to add a web.xml (or web-fragement.xml) for that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there anyhing I have to consider when mixing web.xml and java config?

Comment: Make sure you use the version 3.0 of the xsd and don't set `metadata-complete` to `true`. That should be it.